# Suppress null dates or outside date range

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to suppress certain data if the date falls outside the date range parameter, or if the date field is null. Why is this not suppressing properly?

```
isnull({@DateRejected}) and {?Date Received} <> {@DateRejected}
```

I can't use selection expert to exclude these results because other data from the results needs to remain in the report.

---

[image]

---

The two rows of data shown should be suppressed; one is null, and the other is outside the date range 4/1/17 - 6/30/17.

Comment: What data you want to suppress. Can you add a sample screen shot and point out the expected result?

Comment: edited the response to answer the question

Comment: I am not sure if you need to suppress rows or you need to filter rows.

Comment: Just want to suppress those 5 fields based on the formula

Comment: @4444 answer did not work for you? it should be a *date range check* not *not-equal* check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyword:

> I want to suppress certain data if the date falls outside the date range parameter, **OR** if the date field is null.

If you use `AND` it only suppresses records that fail both checks, instead of failing one or the other.

Additionally, `<>` is equivalent to "not equals." So you're currently telling it to only suppress records where the date equals the string `4/1/17 - 6/30/17`. None of them do, so they all filter through.

---

**Solution:**

```
ISNULL({@DateRejected})
OR
{@DateRejected} < Minimum({?Date Received}) 
OR
{@DateRejected} > Maximum({?Date Received})
```